# Replace some token with another token in bison

Tags: bison

I want to implement a function like list comprehension.

I will try to provide an example as I don't really know how to phrase this.

This input:

```
half := [ x / 2 for x: integer in a of 100] : scalar
```

Shall produce:

```
double* half=(double*)malloc(100*sizeof(double));
for (int a_i = 0; a_i < 100; ++a_i)
  half[a_i] = a[a_i] / 2;
```

My current implementation:

```
comprehension:
      TK_IDENT TK_ASSGN_COL '[' expr KW_FOR TK_IDENT ':' data_type KW_IN TK_IDENT KW_OF expr ']' ':' data_type { $$ = template("%s* %s = (%s*)malloc(%s * sizeof(%s));\n for (int %s_i = 0; %s_i < %s; ++%s_i)\n%s[%s_i] = %s", $15, $1, $15, $12, $15, $10, $10, $12, $10, $1, $10, $4); }
;
```

Procuces:

```
double* half = (double*)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
  for (int a_i = 0; a_i < 100; ++a_i)
half[a_i] = x / 2;
```

The problem as you can see is I can't think of a way of replacing the instances of the token `x` inside `expr` with `a[a_i]`.

`expr` is quite long but it's yet another implementation of expression matching.

```
expr:
  TK_IDENT {$$ = $1; }//any variable name
  ...
  | expr '+' expr {$$ = template("%s + %s", $1, $3); }
  ...
```

As you can see I want to replace instances of `TK_IDENT` that match the `TK_IDENT($6)` with `TK_IDENT($10)[TK_IDENT($10)_i]`. Is this possible?

Comment: The problem is that you want to parse an expression into something you can later substitute into, rather than a fixed string like you are doing currently.  So you really want the parse tree for the expression, not a string.